# Guides on how to make a m.domain website (adaptive)

Tags: mobile, adaptive-design

I have been trying to find guides on how to make an adaptive (I think that's what it's called) website like m.domain.com. However, all I can find on google are design blogs showing the pros and cons of responsive vs adaptive.

I'm guessing you have to use JavaScript to detect the device or browser of the client, and redirect to a mobile site.

I'f any of you guys know the piece of code i will need to detect and redirect (if that's what you have to do) or a guide to building a mobile site like this, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

Using:

```js
   <script>

if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){

if(document.URL !="http://emilostervig.dk")

  {

    window.location ="http://google.dk";

  }

}

</script>
```

You can redirect to a different site if the user in on a mobile device.